# Open Search Server: Connect custom html meta tags to schema fields

Tags: search-engine, opensearch

I've set up a new OSS to handle search on a forum. The basic setup was rather straight forward but upon tweaking it I've gotten stuck. The issue is that the pages have a custom meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="searchtype" content="construction_collection" />
```

I have set up a field in my Schema with the same name and then added it to the returned fields in the query. However that tag in the result xml is always empty:

```
<result name="response" numFound="173" collapsedDocCount="0" start="0" rows="10" maxScore="2357,006" time="6">
    <doc score="2357,006" pos="0" docId="4008">
        <field name="searchtype"/>
```

and I fail to comprehend how to setup the Parser and Crawler in order to connect these. Some threads here insinuate that it should work automatically, but it doesn't. Surely I need to set up something more. What have I missed?

/Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the HTML parser of OpenSearchServer try to extract only the visible information of the Web page.

It is possible to retrieve information stored in meta only if they use a specific syntax. Your meta should be in the form:

```
<meta name="opensearchserver.field.searchtype" content="contruction_collection" />
```

You can also populate several fields:

```
<meta name="opensearchserver.field.searchtype.anotherfield" content="contruction_collection" />
```

Comment: Super, thank you! The usage of the meta tag was new to me. I saw similiar examples using the div tag, but this is much better. 

FYI the official OSS forum is quite useless atm since it seems that all text snippets with tags are gone from the submissions... E.g. here: [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/opensearchserve/discussion/947148/thread/65e88d58)